# Two button clicks displaying the different current times and refreshing on each click

Tags: java, android, datetime

I am new to android studio and am creating a mobile application. My aim is that the user can click a start/pause button and the current time of each button click is recorded in a textview. 
The code I am using - on the pause button click, it gets the current time however on the start button click it just gets the same time as the pause current time which is invalid. I also wish for the current time to be updated on each button click but it doesn't seem to be working

```
 pause = myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.buttonpause);
    pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
    showdate = myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDate);
    showdate2 = myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDate2);

    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd mm yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    Date = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
    Date2 = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar2.getTime());


    pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
             if (isPressed) {
                 view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
                 Date2 = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
                 showdate2.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));

             }else {
                 view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.start);
                 Date = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
                 showdate.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
             }
             isPressed = !isPressed;
         }
     });
```

Could anyone help me with my problem?

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you're supposed to set the time in the onclick, otherwise you'll always have the same (both wrong, btw) timestamps

Comment: as I am new I am not sure how to do that.. could you give me some help?

Comment: my recommendation: start by learning the basics and some good naming conventions. learn the basic structures before going into more advanced material. this is very simple, on the showDate.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime())); (remove the second Calendar instance) ipv a previously fixed value

Comment: i treid that but it still gives me the same 2 times

Comment: remove these two lines: 
                 Date2 = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
                 Date = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()); they are redundant and you don't use them, you can use the Date variables alltogether. have you debugged your code to verify you get in those if or else blocks, and not that one is ignored, or not run?

Comment: just a question. are your pause and start button two different buttons?

Comment: yea they are but for being able to click one (start) and then pause appear i had to code it like this

Comment: Then the problem is that you have only added the ClickListener to the pause button, not to the start button.

Comment: where do i add the ClickListener

Comment: the same way you do as on pause.setOnClickListener but then start.set...

Comment: but the code i have at he minute allows for once one selected the next button automatically appears continuously

Comment: it may appear, sure. but that doesn't mean that ClickListener is applied to the other button. please, first study the basics if you don't see why this doesn't work

Comment: @Stultuske do you know how to use 2 ClickListeners and for the button icon to change from e.g. start to pause on each button click?

Comment: sure that's possible. just look at how it is set up now. but seriously: study the basics first. you're just trying to alter code you don't understand in order to get a working application

Comment: In your format pattern string you want uppercase `MM` for month (and lowercase for minutes as you already have).

Comment: @OleV.V. would you know the answer to the question or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then try this:

```
    ....
    pause = myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.buttonpause);
    pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
    showdate = myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDate);
    showdate2 = myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDate2);

    // Get Rid of All of this!!
    //calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    //calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    //simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd mm yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    //Date = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
    //Date2 = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar2.getTime());


    pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
             if (isPressed) {
                 view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
                 String now = getDateNow();
                 long nowLong = getMillisecondsNow();
                 Log.e("My Time Milli 1 = ", "" + nowLong )
                 //Date2 = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
                 showdate2.setText(now);

             }else {
                 view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.start);
                 String now = getDateNow();
                 long nowLong = getMillisecondsNow();
                 Log.e("My Time Milli 2 = ", "" + nowLong )
                 //Date = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
                 showdate.setText(now);
             }
             isPressed = !isPressed;
         }
     });

    private String getDateNow() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(""dd mm yyyy HH:mm:ss"");
        return sdf.format(cal.getTime());       
    }
```

This method is just for testing the Calendar. Not for actual time measurement purposes!!

```
private long getMillisecondsNow(){
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    return cal.getTimeInMillis();
}
```

**Disclaimer**: This is a solution based on your question parameters. If you want a time measurement app, then I do not recommend this solution. For truly accurate time measurement use `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();`

Comment: If you need truly accurate elapse time measurements you should use `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();` If that is what you need post a new Question and state your project parameters.

Answer (score 1):

when you click ,you should do this

```
 pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
         if (isPressed) {
             view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
            //do this
             showdate2.setText(getNowDatess("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));

         }else {
             view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.start);
            //do this
             showdate.setText(getNowDatess("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
         }
         isPressed = !isPressed;
     }
 });




 /**
 * get the now time
 * @param formart  yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss or other
 */
public static String getNowDatess(String formart) {
    try {
        return getFormatDate(System.currentTimeMillis(), formart);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
  public static String getFormatDate(long date, String formatString) {
    String formatData;
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(formatString);
    formatData = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
    return formatData;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help, how do I reinitialize the time?

Comment: Encapsulates a method. Each time you use this method, get the current time

Comment: @Fionnuala exactly like I told you in the comments

Comment: @Fionnuala how did you try that? how much time was there between clicking the buttons? ... ?

Comment: i edited the line to read this "showDate.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime())‌​); " and at least a minute

Comment: for both the dates? can you update the code in your question to what you have now?

Comment: @于阔源 That won't help. she just said in the comments she only added a clickListener to the pause button, not to the start button. that's the problem